# Pandas: Sort groups and sort within group

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

My dataframe `df` contains products which have an EAN, an earlier and later date, 'yes' and 'no' labels and values.

```
EAN-Unique  Date         Start  Value 
3324324     2019-04-30   no      0.11
3324324     2018-06-01   yes    56.03
asd2343     2015-03-23   yes     8.02
asd2343     2015-07-11   no      8.45
Xjkhfsd     1999-04-12   yes    12.33
Xjkhfsd     2001-02-01   no      9.11
5234XAR     2013-12-13   no     15.75
5234XAR     2000-12-13   yes     9.00
3434343     1972-05-23   yes     1.26
3434343     1980-11-01   no      2.77
```

I want to sort *the groups of EAN-Uniques* (for example 3324324 is a group, asd2343 is a group and so on) based on

- lowest to highest value based on the earlier date and
- within each group from earlier date to later date.

The `df` shall look as follows:

```
EAN-Unique  Date         Start  Value 
3434343     1972-05-23   yes     1.26
3434343     1980-11-01   no      2.77
asd2343     2015-03-23   yes     8.02
asd2343     2015-07-11   no      8.45
5234XAR     2000-12-13   yes     9.00
5234XAR     2013-12-13   no     15.75
Xjkhfsd     1999-04-12   yes    12.33
Xjkhfsd     2001-02-01   no      9.11
3324324     2018-06-01   yes    56.03
3324324     2019-04-30   no      0.11
```

My attempt was to sort it

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['EAN-Unique','Date','Value'], ascending=[True,True,True]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it didn't work as intended. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: why didn't `df.sort_values(by='EAN-Unique')` work?

Comment: Why 3434343 goes first?

Comment: Because 3434343 has the lowest value of all (for its earliest date).

Comment: So why asd2343 goes second?

Comment: Because asd2343 has the second lowest value of all for its earlier date. And 5234XAR goes third because it has the thirds lowest value of all for its earlier date. And Xjkhfsd goes fourth because it has the fourths lowest value of all for its earlier date. And 3324324 goes fifth because it has the highest value of all for its earlier date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an auxiliary column `seq` to store group order by Start Value

```
group_order = df.sort_values(['Start', 'Value'], ascending=[False, True])['EAN-Unique'].unique()
seq_map =  dict(zip(group_order, range(len(group_order))))
df['seq'] = df['EAN-Unique'].map(seq_map)
df.sort_values(['seq', 'Date'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

```
  EAN-Unique        Date Start  Value  seq
8    3434343  1972-05-23   yes   1.26    0
9    3434343  1980-11-01    no   2.77    0
2    asd2343  2015-03-23   yes   8.02    1
3    asd2343  2015-07-11    no   8.45    1
7    5234XAR  2000-12-13   yes   9.00    2
6    5234XAR  2013-12-13    no  15.75    2
4    Xjkhfsd  1999-04-12   yes  12.33    3
5    Xjkhfsd  2001-02-01    no   9.11    3
1    3324324  2018-06-01   yes  56.03    4
0    3324324  2019-04-30    no   0.11    4
```